# Renderização de Foreign Key no Django

Tags: python, django

Estou utilizando CreateView no django e renderizando meus componentes com widget tweak gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de trocar essa primeira opção da combo

**forma renderizada no template**

`{% render_field form.category class="form-control"  %}`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quer trocar esse valor default do `----------`?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o `initial`, veja:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> class DateForm(forms.Form):
...     day = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today)
```

Ou assim para um texto:

```
>>> class CommentForm(forms.Form):
...     name = forms.CharField()
...     url = forms.URLField()
...     comment = forms.CharField()
>>> default_data = {'name': 'Your name', 'url': 'http://'}
>>> f = CommentForm(default_data, auto_id=False)
```